# Calcular momentos de una imagen después de usar la función de etiquetado de componentes conectados

Tags: python, opencv

Necesito calcular los momentos de Hu de una imagen de entrada. La imagen de entrada `input` consiste en diversos objetos por lo que necesito pre-procesarla utilizando la función de etiquetado de componentes conectados:

```
# imagen de entrada es umbralada
(T, thresh) = cv2.threshold(input, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# obteniendo las etiquetas de los componentes conectados
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
num_labels = output[0]
labels = output[1]
stats = output[2]
centroids = output[3]

# para cada componente conectado en la imagen de salida
for c in centroids[1:num_labels]:
img_moments = cv2.moments(c)
hu = cv2.HuMoments(img_moments)
```

Sin embargo, esto no me esta dando los valores correctos de los momentos de Hu de cada componente. Previamente utilizaba la imagen umbralada para obtener los momentos `cv2.moments(thresh)`, pero esto no es útil cuando hay múltiples componentes dentro de la imagen. Estoy usando Python 2 con OpenCV 3.

Por cierto, ya obtuve correctamente el número de etiquetas de la imagen, en este caso la imagen de entrada tiene 10 componentes + 1 etiqueta para el fondo, eso da un total de 11 etiquetas, se que la primera etiqueta es para el fondo, por lo tanto los valores del arreglo son todos ceros. Quiero obtener los valores del resto de las etiquetas (desde 1 hasta n-etiquetas) y convertir esos valores a un arreglo de Numpy para calcular los momentos individualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí resolver mi problema utilizando la información proporcionada por las estadísticas de salida de cada etiqueta `stats = output[2]`.

Con esta información cree una ROI (Región de interés) por cada componente en la imagen de entrada, y posteriormente calculé los momentos de la imagen y los momentos de Hu de la ROI obteniendo los valores deseados de salida.

La solución propuesta es la siguiente:

```
# por cada componente en la imagen de salida
for label in range(num_labels):

# recuperando la anchura de la caja delimitadora del componente
width = stats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
# recuperando la altura de la caja delimitadora del componente
height = stats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
# recuperando la coordenada mas a la izquierda de la caja delimitadora
x = stats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
# recuperando la coordenada mas alta de la caja delimitadora
y = stats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]

# creando la ROI usando indexación
roi = thresh[y:y+height, x:x+width]

# calculando los momentos de la imagen y los momentos de Hu de la ROI
img_moments = cv2.moments(roi)
hu = cv2.HuMoments(img_moments)
```

Estoy seguro de que hay otras formas de segmentar los componentes conectados en una imagen de entrada, pero en este momento esta solución funciona bien para mí.